# 16 days in Thailand with GoPro Hero 6 Black [Help]

Tags: camera

I'm going to Thailand for 16 days with GoPro Hero 6 and I have three questions because I don't have any experience in this field.

First of all I googled some stats about battery life and how much Mbps does camera take for my case (95% of the time I'm going to use 1080p with 60fps and ProTune on). If I'm correct and for this mode camera will use H.264 codec then stats are as follows:

Battery life (per one charge) : **~1h 40min**

60Mbps = ~ 8MB/s = **~ 28 GB/h**

Am I correct?

Moving on to the second question with given calculated values I estimated that I will need around 3h of content per day. I also decided that I will buy FeiyuTech G5 gimbal which can extra charge my GoPro. I watched some videos on YT, but no one said if this gimbal can charge GoPro from 0-100%. They said that it has around 8h of battery life for itself.

Can I assume that gimbal will work 3h + charge my GoPro from 0-100% on one battery life to match my 3h target?

This is my first trip with camera and I would like to know your opinion about this 3h target per day. I'm not a professional and I will use it only for myself. How much video content do you record on your vacation?

Answer (score 1):

The important factor is not "battery life" as such. It's mAh (milliamp hours) which is how much current the battery pack can deliver for how long.

For example, my battery pack can supply 20,000mAh to one of my devices, which has a battery size of 4,000mAh. So I can fully charge it 5 times from the pack.

As to your other question - I have had days of 10 hours of footage, and others of under 15 minutes. It will depend entirely on what you do and see, the weather, your preferences etc.